# Audio play but video hide in Samsung Smart tv PLAYER plugin with Scene

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, samsung-smart-tv

I am using Scene i.e App Framework in Samsung Smart TV 
for playing video I use

```
sf.core.plugin("PLAYER");
sf.core.plugin("AUDIO");
```

plugins but when I play video only audio is playing and video is hide behind Scene

So is there any way to set Z-index of player so that video will play above the Scene?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to move from plugin player to [Framework Module player](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/API00005/sf.service.VideoPlayer_42.html) is it's still not too late, but when you're insist to use plugin player then you should hide all your visible HTML which covering the player.

With framework player you can set the zIndex and the player will take place of  one of your `<div>` (http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/API00005/sf.service.VideoPlayer_42.html#setZIndex)

Comment: Actually I tried that player I had issue with that coz sometime video is squeezing on that player thats why I decided to use PLAYER plugin Right now I hide/show divs for video thats working But I think that is not correct way there should be some Solution Lets see bdw thanks....and let me know if you find out any related info thanx

Comment: Try to set display area after calling play